# Combine data from different txt

Tags: r, dataframe, text-files

I have 20 different txt which all have the same columns with the same names BUT different values
for example

```
TXT1
a    b   c   d
1    4   5   6
3    4   5   3

TXT2
a    b   c   d
2    4   8   6
3    5   2   9
```

how can i create a new txt which will have all the values from both TXT1 and TXT2 in the correct column?

thank you

Anna

Comment: are TXT1 and TXT2 `data.frames`?  Do you need to know that they're from the respective original data or just want to mash them together?  ?I would add a column with the name of each `data.frame` and then take a look at `?rbind`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your column names are identical, per your above example:

```
    TXT3 <- rbind(TXT1,TXT2)
    write.table(TXT3,file="TXT3.txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

When I include reading the data, I would solve your problem like this:

```
library(plyr)
large_table = ldply(list_src_files, read.table)
write.table(large_table, file = "large_table.txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some R magic to make your life very easy:

Create some data in the format you described:

```
TXT1 <- data.frame(a = 1:4,b = 5:8,c = 9:12)
TXT2 <- data.frame(a = 11:14,b = 15:18,c = 19:22)
TXT3 <- data.frame(a = 21:24,b = 25:28,c = 29:32)
TXT4 <- data.frame(a = 31:34,b = 35:38,c = 39:42)
```

Stich it together:

```
x <- ls(pattern = "TXT[[:digit:]]", all.names=TRUE)
do.call(rbind, lapply(x, get))
```

The results:

```
    a  b  c
1   1  5  9
2   2  6 10
3   3  7 11
4   4  8 12
5  11 15 19
6  12 16 20
7  13 17 21
8  14 18 22
9  21 25 29
10 22 26 30
11 23 27 31
12 24 28 32
13 31 35 39
14 32 36 40
15 33 37 41
16 34 38 42
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you read in your files, use `rbind()` .

Example:

```
dat.in.1 <- read.delim(dat.1)
dat.in.2 <- read.delim(dat.2)
dat.in.3 <- read.delim(dat.3)
dat.in.4 <- read.delim(dat.4)
dat.in.5 <- read.delim(dat.5)

dat.total <- rbind(dat.in.1, dat.in.2, dat.in.3, dat.in.4, dat.in.5)
```

You should also give this a look:
[R Data Import/Export Manual](http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html)

Comment: There is no need to repeat reading for each subfile. Putting the subdata in a list much more efficient. My answer includes an example of using apply style loop to read data.